# General window structure template

Tags: c#, wpf

for my WPF-application I want a specific window structure for all windows in my application:

```
<DockPanel>
 <UCs:Toolbar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
 <UCs:SearchPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

 <ContentControl DockPanel.Dock="Top"
                Content="{Binding}"/>

 <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem Content="Status"/>
 </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

Something like this where I insert the specific user controls in the ContentControl via binding. How can I achieve this?

Because I use this right now for every window:

Window 1:

```
<DockPanel>
 <UCs:Toolbar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
 <UCs:SearchPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

 <DataGrid .../>

 <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem Content="Status"/>
 </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

Window 2:

```
<DockPanel>
 <UCs:Toolbar DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>
 <UCs:SearchPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top"/>

 <Grid.../>

 <StatusBar DockPanel.Dock="Bottom">
    <StatusBarItem Content="Status"/>
 </StatusBar>
</DockPanel>
```

If I want to change the order of the toolbar and SearchPanel I have to modify all my windows. I hope there is a way to handle this better...

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

From easy to difficult but elegant:

1-Create a `ContentControl` that has all the repeated stuff and can host the content which is different in each window. Then in each window, first put your contentcontrol, then your information as its content

2-Create a `ControlTemplate` for `Window` and apply it to your windows.